# Will it be effective/is it safe to run an ozone generator when you have leaks like this?

Tags: leak, paint, ozone-generator

This is not a duplicate.  Other questions ask about the effectiveness of cheap ozone generator - nothing about leaks.  This question asks if leaks affect safe usage of ozone as well as reduce its effectiveness and how to get around it.

Need to run an ozone generator in my car.  However there are some leaks in the boot area which let water into the boot.  They leaks are hard to find.

The worst leak seems to be the bootlid, as you can see from the picture it's slightly raised.  However ever after pouring water over I don't always see massive  water leak through it, though after a rainy day some water would have gone through.  Then again I could probably put tape around it.

1. What type of tape should I use to prevent it damaging the paint work.
2. Will the ozone still be effective even with these leaks? (I really dont want to fix them as it requires a lot of investigation at the moment.)
3. Would it be safe to use? I don't want ozone leaking out harming anybody around it.
   [image: l]

Comment: see https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/68414/10976

Comment: Use a smoke generator to find the leaks.

Comment: @SolarMike this quesion is asking about leaks.

Comment: You were given good instructions - make use of them.

Comment: So you don't harm anyone, you need to correct the leaks.