# how will I know if seat cushion has absorbed to the poinr that it needs replacing or not?

Tags: smell

1. If car leaks caused water to go through the fabric and into the cushion of a seat, then you try to squish it out of the sponge and the surface feels dry, but the inside may/may not have water in it, how can you know if it is free from damp inside or not?  If condensation no longer develops on windows does that mean I am safe from it?
2. Can we say if you don’t feel or smell it it’s not there?  However suppose you smell it but don’t feel it, does this mean it’s an odour that remains or perhaps water is still inside the foam so the source hasn’t been removed?
3. If there is water in the foam, what can I do besides squishing to get it out, maybe remove the seat and leave it out, or put it in a heated room etc? Are there other methods which you can do from the car? the waters only been in a few days so im not sure if its progressed badly though i do notice condensation developing.
4. I guess an ozone machine will not work if there is water in the cushion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will any cheap ozone generator do the job?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/68413/will-any-cheap-ozone-generator-do-the-job)

Comment: @SolarMike I have edited to show what I meant.  This is more about diagnosing and removing water from foam.